# Is this a typo of "is"?

Tags: prepositions

I came across the following sentence in [this page](https://lifehacker.com/waste-phone-scammers-time-instead-of-yours-with-robokil-1824049341).

> Now a new app is making it so the person losing out on time during
>   their day in the scammer on the other end of the line, not me.

I could not understand the structure of the sentence after *in the scammer...*. I suspect there is a typo of **is**. I could understand the sentence if it was

> Now a new app is making it so the person losing out on time during
>   their day **is** the scammer on the other end of the line, not me.

Am I guessing wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think analysing/correcting typos is useful on ELL

Comment: Yes, it's almost certainly a typo.

Comment: I think it's a sensible question - a non-English speaker is not well-placed to know whether this is an unfamiliar idiom or a typo. Especially in this domain, which is relating to modern technology, new idioms ca appear.

Comment: I agree with @djna. OP could probably rephrase their question to fit it better for this site.

Comment: @djna It's a valid question but not an interesting one, IMO, in the sense that it is not likely to be useful to anyone else unless they happened to be reading the same article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you're correct, it should be **is the scammer**